# processes started with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() candidates for killing?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl, audioeffect

The problem with most (if not all) equalizer apps for android is they getting killed when OS runs low on resources. (Some have the ability to restart after a short timeout) If you wear earphones when the app suddenly dies, the volume may suddenly increase to dangerous level.

The idea is to make a separate binary for my equalizer and start it with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. The binary will use the native OpenSLES API to activate audio effects.

Before I even start I want to know: will the child process be a candidate for killing?